# Align 2 different elements inside an accordion button - Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and am trying to align a `<p>` tag and a `<span>` to the left and right, respectively.
I've tried a bunch of different things and I can't make them go to opposite directions if they're inside the button tag. Maybe this is by design but I thought I'd try it here.
Here's my code:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2"
                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2">
                <p class="h5 float-start">Grade 2</p>
                <span class="h5 float-end">1 <i class="fas fa-book"></i></span>
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapse2" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-bs-parent="#accordion2">
            <div class="accordion-body" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
                <a href="http://localhost:8000/cm/unit/3" class="h5">Unit 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p>Some text goes here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the following result (everything is aligned to the left).
[image]

As simple as it may sound, I couldn't make it work after browsing the web for solutions. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: configure width for div and p tags

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I see what you mean. That works, thank you. I left the `<p>` tag at 95% and the other one at 5% and that ended up doing the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For aligning the child element at both ends you can use bootstarp `d-Flex` class

````
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2"
                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2">
                <p class="h5 mb-0 flex-grow-1">Grade 2</p>
                <span class="h5 mb-0 pr-3">1 <i class="fas fa-book"></i></span>
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapse2" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-bs-parent="#accordion2">
            <div class="accordion-body" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
                <a href="http://localhost:8000/cm/unit/3" class="h5">Unit 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p>Some text goes here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>```
````

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best solution. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your button has `display:flex` try setting that to `display:block` and there you go.

```css
.accordion-item .accordion-button {
    display: block;
}
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%230c63e4'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
transform: rotate(
-180deg);
position: absolute;
right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2"
                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2">
                <p class="h5 float-start">Grade 2</p>
                <span class="h5 float-end">1 <i class="fas fa-book"></i></span>
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapse2" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-bs-parent="#accordion2">
            <div class="accordion-body" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
                <a href="http://localhost:8000/cm/unit/3" class="h5">Unit 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p>Some text goes here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, you have to re-position your background (`::after`) for the button

Comment: *It is because your button has `display:flex`* - No it hasn't.